# Is it possible to combine an SQL Select request with a PHP Array with inner join on a comman key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

for example we have this

php array

```
$test = array(array('id'=>1, 'name'=> 'foo'), array('id'=>2, 'name'=> 'bar'));
```

Now the SQL statement

```
$sql='SELECT id, mail FROM user';
```

is there a way to cobine the output ON id to get a new array like

```
$result = array(array('id'=>1, 'name'=> 'foo', mail => 'foo@example.com'), array('id'=>2, 'name'=> 'bar', mail =>'bar@example.com'));
```

Comment: There is no internal function for this - buy you can write it by your own with two foreach one into another.

Comment: How does your table look like? You will have to loop over the result array/object.

Answer (score 0):

For Combine Arrays in php  Use [array_push](https://www.php.net/array_push) Function
you can Combine Array And Array 
Or combine String And Array
By it...